# How to use predefined functions for catching a ROI changed event?

Tags: event-handling, dm-script

Under scripting/Predefined Events/ImageDisplay Listener/
there is a nice example 'class CListen':  a mouse click within an image returns the coordinates of the point of click.
I tried to use the event 'roi_changed' but don't get anything back.
what is missing (see below)?

Help greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

```
class CListen
{              
CListen( object self ) { Result( "\n CListen object " + self.ScriptObjectGetId() + " created in memory."); } 
~CListen( object self ) { Result( "\n CListen object " + self.ScriptObjectGetId() + " removed from memory."); } 


void OnROI_c( object self, Number disp_flags, ImageDisplay disp, Number roi_flags1, Number roi_flags2, ROI theRoi ) 
{
    string nam = "[" + disp.ImageDisplayGetImage().GetLabel() + "]" 
    result( "\n ROI moved in " + nam + " at " + roi_flags1 + " : " + roi_flags2 )
} 
void OnClick( object self, number flags, imageDisplay disp, number mx, number my ) 
{ 
    string name = "[" + disp.ImageDisplayGetImage().GetLabel() + "]" 
    result( "\n Mouse-click in " + name + " at " + mx + " / " + my ) 
} 
} 


{  
image img := RealImage( "Test", 4, 100, 100 ) 
img.ShowImage() 
imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay( 0 ) 
ROI theRoi = NewROI()
theRoi.ROISetRectangle( 10, 10, 40, 40 )
disp.ImageDisplayAddROI( theRoi )
 
object listener = Alloc( CListen ) 
string messagemap = "unassociated_click:OnClick" 
string test =                        "roi_changed:OnROI_c"
number listenID = ImageDisplayAddEventListener( disp, listener, messagemap, test ) 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added your 2nd event not to the message map, but to the (unimportant) ID-string :c)

try this:
(And note the `;` after the first message)

```c
string messagemap = "unassociated_click:OnClick;"
messagemap +=       "roi_changed:OnROI_c" 
string test = "unimportant identification string"
number listenID = ImageDisplayAddEventListener( disp, listener, messagemap, test )
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  One surprise:  moving the ROI via keystroke by one pixel creates three identical entries in the Output window:
 ROI moved in [B] at 65280 : 0
 ROI moved in [B] at 65280 : 0
 ROI moved in [B] at 65280 : 0
Any reason for this?